# Add fee to woocommerce based on product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have a store with a category that uses the "virtual" product type in order to avoid shipping. However, there is a service fee that needs to be added to each order that includes a product of that category.

Through various searches I have found different ways to globally add a fee, or to add a fee based on quantity, and have tried to use that to target via category, but can't seem to get it right.

```
function woo_add_cart_fee() {
global $woocommerce;
//Getting Cart Contents. 
$cart = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
//find product category
foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $_product = $values['data'];
        $terms = get_the_terms( $_product->id, 'product_cat' );
    }
  if ($_categoryid == 23){
      $excost = 6;
  } 
  elseif ($_categoryid == 14){
      $excost = 0;
  }     

$woocommerce->cart->add_fee('Service Charge', $excost, $taxable = false, $tax_class = '');
}   
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee' );
```

Comment: Check the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26240591/add-a-fee-to-woocommerce-per-product-based-on-category