# Add a fee to WooCommerce per product, based on category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been trying for a while now to get this working but I haven't find any solution that does exactly what we need, and I'm far from an expert in PHP so I'm a bit lost.

We use WooCommerce and WooTickets. The goal is to add a 5% fee for "Service Fee" only to products in the "Tickets" category (ID:34).

We have found this code snipper, that add a fixed cost based on a product category :

```
// Add Service Fee to Category
function woo_add_cart_fee() {

$category_ID = '23';
global $woocommerce;

foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {
    // Get the terms, i.e. category list using the ID of the product
$terms = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_cat' );
    // Because a product can have multiple categories, we need to iterate through the list of the products category for a match
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        // 23 is the ID of the category for which we want to remove the payment gateway
        if($term->term_id == $category_ID){
         $excost = 6;
         }
         }
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee('Service Fee', $excost, $taxable = false, $tax_class = '');
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee' );
```

The main problem with this solution is that it adds a fixed cost, whereas we need a percentage cost.

We also found this code snippet from WooThemes themselves :

```
/**
 * Add a 1% surcharge to your cart / checkout
 * change the $percentage to set the surcharge to a value to suit
 * Uses the WooCommerce fees API
 *
 * Add to theme functions.php
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
  global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $percentage = 0.05;
    $surcharge = ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total ) * $percentage;    
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Service Fee', $surcharge, true, 'standard' );

}
```

But once again, there are a few problems with this solution...

1) The product category is not taken into consideration
2) It adds a fee based on the entire cart value, but it should only add a 5% fee to products in the "Tickets" product category, not the entire cart

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was having the same issue and came across a code snippet that set me on the correct path.  For the life of me, I cannot find the original site that housed the snippet, but here is my reworked version.

```php
function df_add_ticket_surcharge( $cart_object ) {

    global $woocommerce;
    $specialfeecat = 86; // category id for the special fee
    $spfee = 0.00; // initialize special fee
    $spfeeperprod = 0.05; //special fee per product

    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {

        $proid = $value['product_id']; //get the product id from cart
        $quantiy = $value['quantity']; //get quantity from cart
        $itmprice = $value['data']->price; //get product price

        $terms = get_the_terms( $proid, 'product_cat' ); //get taxonamy of the prducts
        if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $catid = $term->term_id;
                if($specialfeecat == $catid ) {
                    $spfee = $spfee + $itmprice * $quantiy * $spfeeperprod;
                }
            }
        endif;  
    }

    if($spfee > 0 ) {

        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Ticket Concierge Charge', $spfee, true, 'standard' );
    }

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'df_add_ticket_surcharge' );
```

This will add a 5% surcharge to each item in the cart with the category of ticket (id: 86).  I hope this helps you out, if you have not found a solution already.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer @Bartoszkp / @Sartorius!
Pushing the logic a bit farther, how would you change the fee dynamically based on the quantity? For example, let's say you have a 5% fee if there are less than 10 tickets, 2.5% fee if there is 11 to 20 tickets and no fee at all if there is over 20 tickets?

Would something like that work :

`if($specialfeecat == $catid ) {
    if($quantity <= '10') {
                    $spfee = $spfee + $itmprice * $quantiy *  ($spfeeperprod / 2);}
                }`

Thank you again for the help!

Answer (score 3):

thanks for posting this above code. I had needed exactly this, but there were some problems for, me. I didn't want the category to be a part of it, i wanted it to apply to all products, and I also required a fixed fee per product.

The other problem I had was if I had 2 different products in the cart it would only calculate it as 1 product. so I did some research and found a way for it to calculate the total number of products in the cart. So here is the final code I came out with. Thought it may help someone else looking for a similar answer

```
/** add handling fee **/
function df_add_handling_fee( $cart_object ) {

global $woocommerce;
// $specialfeecat = 3711; // category id for the special fee
$spfee = 0.00; // initialize special fee
$spfeeperprod = 10; //special fee per product

//Getting Cart Contents. 
$cart = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
//Calculating Quantity
foreach($cart as $cart_val => $cid){
   $qty += $cid['quantity']; 
}
foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {

    $proid = $value['product_id']; //get the product id from cart
    //$quantiy = $value['quantity']; //get quantity from cart
    $itmprice = $value['data']->price; //get product price

    $terms = get_the_terms( $proid, 'product_cat' ); //get taxonamy of the prducts
    if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            //$catid = $term->term_id;
            //if($specialfeecat == $catid ) {
                $spfee = $qty * $spfeeperprod;
            //}
        }
    endif;  
}

if($spfee > 0 ) {

    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Handling Fee', $spfee, true, 'standard' );
}

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'df_add_handling_fee' );
```

As you can see I have just commented out the parts from the original code. Hope someone can benefit from this :)