# WooCommerce fixed extra fee per product of certain category BUT with conditions

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, theming

I'm developing a WooCommerce site. I need to have following functionality:
Products of a certain three categories needs to have extra delivery fee added per product. 
This was already covered here:
[Add a fee to WooCommerce per product, based on category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26240591/add-a-fee-to-woocommerce-per-product-based-on-category)

I already have fixed shipping fees
- X bucks homeland, but if cart value over 250, no shipping fee
- Z bucks some countries, but if cart value over 250, no shipping fee
- Y bucks rest of the world, but if cart value over 250, no shipping fee

Now, for these three categories new should have
- X bucks homeland + extra fee (10 bucks); but if cart value over 250, no shipping fee and no extra fee
- Z bucks some countries + extra fee (30 bucks); but if cart value over 250, only extra fee.
- Y bucks rest of the world + extra fee (50 bucks); but if cart value over 250, only extra fee.

There might be plugins for this, but I'd rather not...

Comment: are you searching for a plugin?

Comment: I'd prefer not to use plugin for this.

Comment: What I need: Add fixed fee to product of a category when sent to certain area. If cart amount over something, then free or then not, depending of zone.

Comment: Do you know coding?

Comment: Some, but I was after a snippet to modify.

Comment: Please post the snippet, chance to get your answer will be high